# Array formula not working, what do I have wrong?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Why is this formula not working? Trying to find the next date equal or greater than today in column K but using a query to filter out some items. Thanks for the help.

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY(Sheet1!B6:K,"select K where B contains '303'")TO_DATE(MIN(if(Sheet1!K:K>=today(),Sheet1!K:K'!K:K))))`

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please use a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please add either: a link to (a copy of) your Google Sheet, screenshots, or a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=MIN(
  QUERY(
    Sheet1!B6:K,
    "SELECT K
     WHERE     B CONTAINS '303'
           AND K >= toDate(now())"
  )
)
```

Or:

```
=MIN(
  FILTER(
    Sheet1!K6:K,
    REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!B6:B, "303"),
    Sheet1!K6:K >= TODAY()
  )
)
```